# Элемент возвращает старое значение origin.y

Tags: swift

У меня есть экран на котором пользователь может вводить данные в поля расположенные друг под другом и на первом поле висит обработчик:

```
func didChangeTextFood(textField:UITextField) {

    if(Food.text! != ""){

        FoodNote.hidden = false

        FoodNote.frame.size.height = 30

        if(FoodHide){

            self.Label1.frame.origin.y += 30

            self.Label2.frame.origin.y += 30
            self.Label3.frame.origin.y += 30

        }
        FoodHide = false

    }else {
        if(!FoodHide){
            self.Label1.frame.origin.y -= 30

            self.Label2.frame.origin.y -= 30
            self.Label3.frame.origin.y -= 30
        }
        FoodHide = true
        FoodNote.hidden = true
        FoodNote.frame.size.height = 0
    }
}
```

То есть у меня стоит обработчик на текстовом поле, который смотрит, если поле не пустое - мы спускаем остальные поля (под нашим полем) на 30 пикселей ниже и это работает, до момента, пока мы не кликнем по другому полю, экрану, либо чему-либо ещё. Тогда `Label1`, `Label2` и `Label3` просто возвращаются на свои прежние места и просто перекрывают поле, которое мы вывели (`FoodNote.hidden=false`).
В чём может быть проблема? Может потому что у меня прописаны Constraints вида `Top Space to: Food`?

Comment: Может быть я как-то неправильно описал проблемы или ещё что, потому что бьюсь с ней уже не первый день, а решения так и не нашёл

Comment: ставтьте тэг `iOS`, больше людей увидит вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть кому-нибудь поможет, я это решил так:

Поле Food (UITextField) и скрытое поле FoodNote я поместил в отдельный View, указав ему constaint высоты (height) и обозвал его (View)  FoodView. Остальные поля (которые находятся под ним), я поставил constaint`ом отступ от верхнего элемента на 10 пикселей (то есть у Label1 отступ был от FoodView, у Label2 от Label1 и т.д.)
И при заполнении поля выполнялась такая функция:

```
let newButtonConstraintL = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.FoodView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 60)
self.view.addConstraints([newButtonConstraintL])
```

То есть раньше была высота 30, а после ввода текста - становится 60, а остальные элементы, поскольку отступают от нашего View - тоже смещаются.

Я не знаю на сколько это правильно, но ничего лучше я не нашёл. Надеюсь кому-нибудь поможет